# Wake laptop when lid is opened?

Tags: suspend

I have a SAMSUNG laptop, which by the experience in the last months, has been a great one. I am actually implementing some functionality to it, and since I noticed, I am able to wake up my laptop from sleep by just opening the lid on Windows 7, however, I need to press to power button to wake up in Ubuntu. Using a program called i-nex, I noted that the kernel DOES dettect a "lid switch", and I am looking forward to use it to wake up function. Any ideas?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Thanks *@yossile* for bringing up some clues! However, output of command `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` does not show the LID device. I still tried the second set of commands you gave me with no effect. Then I tried experimenting, guessing that LID should be named by other value, so I tried enabling the others. No victory so far. But I noticed that devices that did not have any pci listings were disabled at all time no matter what I tried. Here is the output of command `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`:

```
root@samsung:~# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PCE4      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:04.0
SBAZ      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.2
P0PC      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.4
GEC       S4    *disabled  
PE20      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:15.0
PE21      S4    *disabled  
PE22      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:15.2
PE23      S4    *disabled  
PWRB      S5    *enabled
```

So maybe it could be that LID is either GEC,PE21, or PE23?

Still, there is /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state file which shows that LID is opened.
Any more ideas?

Comment: does anything in this link help you? http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug#header-0

Comment: not at all, sleep is working on my laptop, i want to set the laptop switch status as "wake-up" when opened. but thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can check whether the Lid open event is configured to wake up your OS by executing the `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` command.
If the status of the '*LID*' device is currently disabled you can try enabling it by executing:

```
sudo -s
echo "LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

This will set the status to enabled.
Running the commands again will set it back to disabled.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted thought to disable wakeup on opening the lid. Thanks.

Comment: My /proc/acpi/wakeup didn't contain LID but LID0 instead. Thus 
echo "LID0" > /proc/acpi/wakeup did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: My `/proc/acpi/` directory contains only `button/lid/LID0` on my Sony VAIO (which wakes in Windows when opening the lid, but neither echoing `LID` or `LID0` into `wakeup` gets the desired behavior.

Comment: If you want to do the opposite and disable wakeup on lid open, the `echo "LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup` toggles from enabled to disable and back. And in my case as @gumkins mentions it was `LID0` for me not `LID`

Comment: In my HP EliteBook 8460p, I have no LID option in this file :(

Comment: @gene_wood and yossile: thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also had to set in BIOS, to use sleep optimized for linux instead of windows.