# How can I enable automatic resume on lid open?

Tags: power-management

My problem is the opposite of what is described in *[How to prevent resume from sleep/suspend on lid open?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8056/how-to-prevent-resume-from-sleep-suspend-on-lid-open)*.

If I close my laptop's lid, it automatically suspends, but when I open it up again, nothing happens, and I have to press the power button to wake it up.
**How can I make my laptop wake up from suspend when I open it's lid?**

*( It's an acer v5-171 running Ubuntu 13.10)*

Comment: I've got this on two separate laptops both running 13.10, but different processors and drivers. So I think it is a bug. Do you also get error messages popping up after every restart?

Comment: @comrademike Yes I get those error messages, but I've also had that in 13.04 on a different computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wake laptop when lid is opened?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102434/wake-laptop-when-lid-is-opened)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs to be supported by hardware through a sensor for the lid-open event. Unless your hardware supports it, there would be "no-one" who will get notified of the "lid-open" event, and wake your laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102434/wake-laptop-when-lid-is-opened) post?  It looks like the method worked for one guy but not the other, so its not a guaranteed fix, but its worth a shot. : )

Here's a brief summary:

> You can check whether the Lid open event is configured to wake up your
>   OS by executing
>   `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`.
>   If the status of LID or LID0 is disabled you can try enabling it by executing
>
> ```
> sudo -s
> echo "LID" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
> ```
>
> This will set the status to enabled, and executing the commands again will set it back to
>   disabled.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working. There's no `LID` device in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. I tried enabling all disabled devices, but non of them did anything noticeable.

Comment: It could be that the laptop has no sensor for lid open. For example, I am quite convinced that this is the case for my Samsung Chronos 7. So in this case resume on lid open is impossible... does it work in other OSes?

Comment: If closing the lid makes it suspend, it would follow that there is a sensor.  Generally the screen will at least turn off when you close the lid of a laptop, so I assume there must be one.

Comment: @Rmano I only ever had Ubuntu on this machine, so I can't answer that. However it clearly knows when it's closed so there must be a sensor for it. Another possibility is that there's no BIOS support for this feature.

Comment: Just because there's a sensor to detect the lid clsoing doesn't mean that there's an event generator in the laptop and it's BIOS to generate a wake up even when it's opened. MOST laptops do not generate lid open events. Of the 10 or so I've used and owned int e the last few years only two do, my Asus N56 and my Acer Chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system utilities and then go to system settings. From there you will pick boot options and scroll down until you see power up on lid opening. Activate and apply.