# Can I add un-suspend when lid is open

Tags: lid

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04 dual-boot. And in both the systems, I have "Suspend when lid is closed" configured. And I was wondering if I could get "Un-suspend when lid is open" in my computer. My computer is an acer aspire 1. If there is such a way to do this, Could anyone suggest how?

Thanks.

Comment: What, so your computer does no awake from suspend when you open your lid?

Comment: @Toroidal I know its not the end of the world, its just that it would be nice to have that.

Comment: So what actually happens when you open your lid? How do you get it out of suspend if it does not do that automatically? Do you have to press your power button or something?

Comment: @Toroidal Yes, I have to press my power button or my space key

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable automatic resume on lid open?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/400955/how-can-i-enable-automatic-resume-on-lid-open)

Comment: @Toroidal maybe my hardware doesnt support it, but if it doesnt support lid is open, can i do, "When lid is not closed and the computer is in suspend, wake up" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this. The feature that some laptops have where they wake up as soon as the lid is open is a BIOS controlled feature. The OS has no control over this since it's asleep and can't monitor/control anything in this state. You'd need to edit your BIOS somehow, which is not a good idea.